# Photoshop CS5 not recognising activeDocument

Tags: javascript, photoshop, flash-cs5, photoshop-script

I wrote a quite big script for Photoshop CS5.1 on my 64bit Vista machine. Now when I run the very same script on my new 64bit Windows 7 machine, Adobe ExtendScript Tool complains about `activeDocument` (no such element) in this simple script:

```
#target photoshop
var pDoc = app.activeDocument;
alert("Done!");
```

I have tried both and without `#target` and choosing the target in the ExtendedScript Tool.
Is there something I have missed, or do I need to install something more. I only installed the 64bit version of Photoshop. Is it so that the 32bit Photoshop has the script extensions?

I don't see why I need to install both 32bit and 64bit versions if I'm only going to use the 64bit version.

Comment: If you've solve the problem, it's best to write your solution as an answer, and accept that.

Comment: I don't think you can answer your own question right away. Some time has to pass... I have answered my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED
The mystery is solved. It is embarrassing simple if you interpret the error message more careful. Of course I can't get an activeDocument if there are no documents in Photoshop, duh!?!
I interpreted it as the statement activeDocument wasn't recognised, but of course if I have no document there is no such element (as a photoshop document) to give me. I'm used to C++ and would expect the reuslt to be a NULL value or similar if there is a problem to get the document... excuses, excuses ;)

Well, if someone else should get into the same problem, here is the answer on my expense :D
I will uninstall the 32bit version now...