# Javascript resize image in different sizes where only the width matters

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am trying to make a script for Photoshop which resizes an open image in different sizes where only the width matters. The goals is to after every resize it should reinstate the original state of the image and run for a different width. There are some scripts online which nearly do this but I only get errors. The error I get is "undefined is not an object".

I have the following script at the moment but I am stuck:

```js
// get a reference to the current (active) document and store it in a variable named "doc"
doc = app.activeDocument;


// these are our values for the END RESULT width and height (in pixels) of our image
var fWidth = 940;


// our web export optionsvar options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();

function SaveJPEG(saveFile, quality) {
  var exportOptionsSaveForWeb = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
  exportOptionsSaveForWeb.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
  exportOptionsSaveForWeb.includeProfile = false;
  exportOptionsSaveForWeb.interlaced = false;
  exportOptionsSaveForWeb.optimized = true;
  exportOptionsSaveForWeb.quality = 80;


}


var newName = 'F' + doc.name + '.jpg';

doc.exportDocument(File(doc.path + '/' + newName), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);

doc.activeHistoryState = doc.historyStates.index(0);
```

The undefined error is stopping the script at the var newName line. I have to add that is for Photoshop CS6.

Any help would be very appreciated thanks.

Comment: It appears that `app.activeDocument` is undefined. Is `documents.length != 0`? (from [Photoshop scripting: app.activeDocument is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22507865/1115360)

Comment: Doesn't matter since the document image is opened with an image. At least that is the way I interpret and I don't get an error on this line.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with setting `doc = app.activeDocument;`, it's just that it could have a value of `undefined`. Then when you try to get `doc.name` it fails because `undefined` does not have `.name` property. Did you check `documents.length`?

Comment: You could do this task with actions and the "Automate > Fit Image" option, you don't need an script for that. But anyway, maybe if you describe the steps that you follow to run the script we will detect where is the error.

Comment: You don't have to "reinstate the original state of the image". Duplicate the Image, work with the Copy, Resize, Save or whatever, Close, Duplicate the Image... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that it's breaking your script, you should try to use the try..catch statement

```
...

var newName;

try {
  newName = 'F' + doc.name + '.jpg';
} catch (e) {
  newName = 'F' + 'name-error' + '.jpg';
  console.log('doc.name is not accessible: ' + e.message;);
}

...
```