# Photoshop Script - How to check if any document is open?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

How do I check if any document is open in Photoshop?

Through Photoshop Script

I've tried `activeDocument.length`, but it returns that activeDocument is not defined.

I wanted something like this:

```
if(documents.open === 0){
    alert('NO DOCUMENT');
} else {
    alert('DOCUMENT OPEN');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close, but no banana. You want

```
documents.length
```

See it here:

```
  if (documents.length == 0)
  {
      alert("No files open to work with, dude!")
  }
```

Comment: It returns an error saying `documents`is undefined in Photoshop CC 2014. What can the problem be?

Comment: alert(documents.length); \\ 0 Works fine in CS2 [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183285/photoshop-cs5-not-recognising-activedocument) may help you

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. I was targeting the script in toolkit and not Photoshop. It works now, thanks! ;)